# Is there anyway to lock or freeze qcombobox to prevent user to change index in qtcreator?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qcombobox

I am new at QtCreator and c++. I am trying to prevent user to change qcombobox index after choosing once. I tried to delete all items and after add only the choosen value but its very long way to do. I couldn't find any function to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is. Do you maybe want to know how to lock a `QComboBox` after the user has set the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locking a `QComboBox` while the user interacts with it is usually not a good idea in terms of user experience.

A `QComboBox` is, like any other `QWidget`, locked by disabling it using
[`QWidget::setEnabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop).
This will also change its color (it is "grayed-out"), to signalize that the user cannot interact with it anymore.

You can connect to the `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` signal to achieve your goal:

```
connect(my_combo_box, qOverload<int>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), [my_combo_box]() {
    my_combo_box->setEnabled(false);
});
```

Note that the usage of `qOverload` requires C++14.